# Google Play store: edit one of the images of my app

Tags: android, google-play

I see guides out there on how to upload a new version of your app to Google store, but in my case I'm not interested in uploading a new apk, I would just like to change one of the uploaded preview images of my app:

[image]

What would be the easiest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Hi you have to go in the Play console, in "Store presence" section of your app, and in "Store listing", here you can change the listing of your app : the description, screenshots,... and all the information

Comment: I'm sorry but after I change the screenshots, do I need to create a new version? Or just save the changes? Because I did change the screenshots but it didn't update in the store. Thanks

Comment: Just save the changes, no need for a new apk, it can takes some time

Comment: How about replacing an existing image with order preserved?